# Converting Pointers in C to C#

Tags: c#, c, pointers

I need to convert some C that uses pointers into C#.

Essentiay I am given a buffer of unformated data and need to treat it
as if if it were formatted. It is usually read froma file but it may not be
it could come from an emmbedded C application running different hardware.

In this example I need to treat it as an array of long.

I C I simply take create a pointe to long and then cast the address of the buffer.

but in C# I am not alowed to take the address of a managed object
and it wont let me cast a byte[] to a long[]

so how to I do this properly in c#

```
void TestFunction(void)
{
    char buffer[256];
    PrintBufferAsLongPointer(buffer);
    PrintBufferAsLongArray(buffer);
}

void PrintBufferAsLongPointer(char *buffer)
{
    long *ptr = (long*)buffer;
    for(int count = 0; count < 64; count++)
    {
        printf(" %X", *ptr++);
    }
}

void PrintBufferAsLongArray(char *buffer)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < 64; index++)
    {
        printf(" %X", buffer[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer, you don't do that kind of stuff in C#. While you *can*, you almost never use pointers in C#. .NET and its managed languages were explicitly designed to prevent unverifiable code, and pointer arithmetic and type casts go against that. If you really must play around with memory addresses and memory layout etc., have a look at `unsafe` code, the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` static class, `StructLayout`, and the like. But know that this won't result in idiomatic C# code. Use typed arrays instead. Or, if you have to do much low-level stuff, stay with C.

Comment: The `long` in C++ and C# do not have the same length. You probably want to use `int` in C#. You can take an array of bytes (`byte[]`) and convert every 4 bytes into an int with BitConverter.ToUInt32 ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use pointers in C# if you're careful (and enable 'unsafe code' in the project options):

```
private static unsafe void PrintBufferAsLongArray(byte[] buffer)
{
    fixed (byte* pBuffer = buffer)
    {
        long* longData = (long*)pBuffer;
        for (int index = 0; index < 64; index++)
            Console.WriteLine(" {0:X}", longData[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you choose to do this?

Comment: @David: Because it's a simple, direct translation. Obviously there's more .NET-y ways of doing this using managed arrays and so forth, but we don't really have enough information in the question to know whether it's viable to change the entire application design to work with a semantic object model (which requires deserialization and reserialization, too) instead of slabs of bytes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Optimized code, the only C# pointers I've ever used was for image analysis.  Took the time down from 5 seconds to a couple ms.  One thing C++ can definitely do better than C# is scan arrays.

Comment: FWIW, it should be `int` rather than `long`

Comment: I want to do this beacause I am writing a test application for an embedded C project and it needs a GUI interface. I want to see what is possible before I make a decision on the solution. The obvious thingis to write a GUI and use some the C source directly so I don't introduce new programming errors.

Comment: The above example is simple compared to what I actually need to do. The buffer does not always have the same format of data in it. in this example I actually need to convert to an array of int and then do some further arithmetic, not just print the values

Comment: You are correct it is long in my C code but it would be int in c# however sometimes the data is an array of short, and sometimes its an array of struct.

Comment: I think it may be easier to compile the relavent C functions into a DLL and link them to the c# app

Comment: I was hoping for some elegant c# solution that doesn't need pointers but it seems that C realy is better for some things.

Comment: This is missing the unsafe section and the compile option in properties but has allowed me to run about 90% of my C code as c# with very few changes. Which means I can be sure my already fully tested code still works and is bug free. The array of struct is a corner case and can be done differntly. I will eventually use BitConverter to get rid of the pointers but this can be done a step at a time so I don't break anything

Comment: @Simon: Yes, using P/Invoke and calling the C functions from C# that way may be better in this case. Regardless, it's also possible to create structures in C# too that match the layout of your C structures, and cast the pointers again just as in C. The `unsafe` keyword is present in the function declaration, by the way :-)

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice the unsafe in the function definition. I didn't know it could be used there. If I can have a pointer a struct and to the content of a struct then that may solve the problem. I tend to shy away from struct in C# because they never behave how I want them to. I just creat an object instead. (it usually has something to do with arrays in the struct or arrays of struct in case you are wondering, structs ar more flexible in C)

Answer (score 2):

In c# the management of memory is done automatically by the .net framework with the help of many components. One of them is the garbage collector, which is responsible for clearing the memory from unused objects. On the other hand, in c the memory is handled by the programmer. The programmer has full access to the memory. He can create and destruct objects. He can make use of pointers to referring to certain places in program's virtual memory and so on. That being said, I would suggest you avoid to convert a program written in c (or in any other language) to a program in c#.

First, think about what you want to implement and then try to find out how this can be implemented in the language of your choice.

I think that you need is the following:

```
void static PrintBuffersContents(char[] buffer)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < buffer.Length; index++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(buffer[index])
    }
}
```

Creating a simple console application you could test the above.

I would like to point out here that you could make use of pointers in c#. I **don't** claim that it is impossible. However, this is not the strong part of c#. If you could avoid them, I would suggest you do. There are many other parts of this language that makes it stronger in certain areas than c. For a detailed explanation of pointer in c#, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `BitConverter.ToInt32()` is what you are looking for.

The following program prints 1, 2, 257, 514.

```
  static void PrintBufferAsInt(byte[] buffer)
  {
     for(int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i+=4)
     {
        var value = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, i);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
     }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     var buffer = new byte[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0};
     PrintBufferAsInt(buffer);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks this may get me most of the way there, It will help with the arrays of simple types anyway. The array of struct might need a bit more thinking about.